# Rowcount number for a Matrix when you add new data point (variable) in available report builder dataset

Tags: sql-server, dataset

I have difficulties with counting row number in Matrix.

I had tried different expressions but none of them work properly, instead of showing row number the expression shows variable count of columns.

The expression I used:

```
rownumber(nothing),
countrow, and ....
```

The solution I found was to divide the number which returns from the expression to the column number, then it will show the correct number of rows.

[image]

Then I came to another problem with my report in different time filter.
After connecting my SQL database to report builder, I decide to add new entry to the SQL dataset, so when I do time filtering in the run report for the time that new entry was not in the dataset, the row number calculation completely ruined. And it is because the SQL database does not count new entry for previous time.

I hope my issue is clear, and if some one else had the same problem with the report builder RowNumber with above condition I would appreciate to help me solve the issue.

My desire table should be like below (a table contain different variables in columns and a timestamp column and variable and timestamps values in rows), instead of Error, I need to have row number.(To build such a table I should have use a matrix in Microsoft report builder, if there is any other way I would appreciate to have advice)

[image]

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Matrices, so what does this have to do with SQL Server? The image *looks* like it might be a snippet of an SSRS expression builder dialogue window.

Comment: Please share desired output

Comment: I am using Microsoft report builder which SQL server is its backbone, so you think I should not use matrices at all??